# cURL default GET request isn't recognized by PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to create a simple Web service that has to return various HTTP codes depending on some conditions, mainly the existence of files related to the specific resources requested via URI. However, i'm stuck on a really strange behaviour i keep getting when I try to generate a 404 header via PHP.

The first snippet, that works, is as follows:

```
$isNotFound = TRUE;
if ($isNotFound) header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
```

Using a simple command-line cURL to request the URI behind which this script runs, I get:

```
$ curl -LI http://www.example.com/
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Wed, 18 Sep 2013 20:57.25 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: clse
Content-Type: text/html
```

Now, the second take is like this:

```
$isNotFound = FALSE;
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
    $isNotFound = TRUE;
}
if ($isNotFound === TRUE) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
}
```

Running cURL again, this time I get this:

```
$ curl -LI http://www.example.com/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: ...
```

The header is the same as the former, except for the code. To check the obvious, I also printed the value of `$isNotFound` just before the last `if`, and it was indeed evaluated to `TRUE`, so the `header` call with the 404 code should be executed. I also added an `exit()` inside the last `if`, and another `header()` at the end of the script, giving other codes in response (like 302), and the result is always that the `header` inside the `if` is ignored.

I managed to make the second script work by explicitly specifying the request method as `GET` in the cURL call:

```
$ curl -X GET -LI http://www.example.com/
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: ...
```

I also had the doubt that cURL wasn't using `GET` as the default method, but printing the `$_SERVER` array showed that the request method was indeed `GET`.

So, what is the reason of this strange behaviour? Is cURL's fault when using the implicit GET method, or is something happening inside PHP? Or maybe i'm so tired that i'm missing something trivial?

Thank you guys, and sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time read the manual:

```
-I, --head
          (HTTP/FTP/FILE) Fetch the HTTP-header only! HTTP-servers feature the 
          command HEAD which this uses to get nothing  but the header of a 
          document. When used on an FTP or FILE file, curl displays the 
          file size and last modification time only.
```

(or your webserver log files, or your TCP stream)

Comment: I know it...I'm sorry but i can't see how is this answer related to my question.

Comment: @swahnee You are making a HEAD request not a GET request.  If you add -v to your curl call you'll see that in your header.  Or, you can change the -I to a -D file.  That will still print the response header to the file, but will send a GET request.

Comment: Oh, nice...thank you! I was fooled by PHP $_SERVER printing that kept telling me that that was a GET request. And sorry to symcbean if i didn't get that little "HEAD" word before :)